# one single scroll button that scrolls to multiple elements in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, button, scroll

I have the next problem: let's say that I have 6 divs with height 700px and one single fixed button.

```
< a class="button >< /a>

< div class="div1" >< /div >
...
< div class="div6 " > < /div >.
```

and every time the user clicks that single fixed button I want to be scrolled down to the next div and so on. Like a carousel (but on vertical).

E.g. the user only sees div1 then he presses the button and it's automatically scrolled to div2. Then he clicks the button again and it's scrolled down to div3, and so on with a little smooth effect.

Here is what I did, but it only works one time:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".div1").offset().top},
    'slow');
});
```

I know how to to this but with 6 different buttons and yeah, that's not the best idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

JS

```
var count = 0,
    sections = $('.section'),
    scrollTo = function(index){
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: sections.eq(index).offset().top
      }, 'slow');
    };


$(".next").click(function(){
  count++;  
  scrollTo(count);
});

$(".prev").click(function(){
  count--;  
  scrollTo(count);
});
```

CSS

```
.navigation { 
  position: fixed;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.section {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
  font-size: 100px;
  height: 700px;
  line-height: 700px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navigation">
  <button class="next">Next</button>
  <button class="prev">Prev</button>
</div>

<div class="sections">
  <div class="section">1</div>
  <div class="section">2</div>
  <div class="section">3</div>
  <div class="section">4</div>
  <div class="section">5</div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/kieran/pen/RBjwoK)

Comment: MANY THANKS, THIS WAS USEFUL

Comment: glad I could help